# Display the total count button is clicked in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to increment the count when the button is clicked.. But in my code the count is incremented when the page is refreshed.. I want to do increment the count only when button is clicked.. I want to take stop the count when the page is refreshed.. the code is working fine when button is clicked it is incremented but when we refresh the page the count is also incremented.. When page is refreshed count should not be incremented. How can I do it

```
<?php
$vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];

//get content of textfile
$filename = "poll_result.txt";
$content = file($filename);

//put content in array
$array = explode("||", $content[0]);
$yes = $array[0];
$no = $array[1];

if ($vote == 0)
  {
  $yes = $yes + 1;
  }
if ($vote == 1)
  {
  $no = $no + 1;
  }

//insert votes to txt file
$insertvote = $yes;
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
fputs($fp,$insertvote);
fclose($fp);
?>    
<table>
<tr>


</td>
</tr>
</table>



<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getVote(int)
    {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_vote.php?vote="+int,true);
    xmlhttp.send();


    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
      {
      if (localStorage.clickcount)
        {
        localStorage.clickcount=Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
        }
      else
        {
        localStorage.clickcount=1;
        }
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="You have voted " + localStorage.clickcount + " times before this session";
      }
    else
      {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
      }
    }

    </script>

    </head>
    <body bgcolor=#5D003D>
    <div id="poll">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `localStorage`, which is not reset on refresh. The easiest way is to reset it on load (`<body bgcolor=#5D003D> onload='localStorage.clickcount=0'>`.